# react redirect to router url after click and display default page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I have a `Header` component like:

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3><Link to="/:one">One</Link></h3>
        <h3><Link to="/:two">Two</Link></h3>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Header
```

and in my `App.js`:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

My intention here is to show header all the time like navbar..

and I have router like:

```
const routes =  (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="/:login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/:one" component={One} />
        <Route path="/:two" component={Two} />
  </Route>
)
export default routes
```

Here in my `Header` when I click on `One` or `Two` it should redirect in that page.

Also the main thing I want is I want `Header` component in every page.. Like navbar..

In my `App.js` I have only `Header` component. When I go to `/` in the browser it should show `Login` page as default..

I need guide to go through this..

I am very new to react

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I recommend you read the react-router docs, as it seems like you are not understanding what `path` and `to` are doing. `path` is matching a pattern and you just wrote the same pattern 3x, and you wrote a pattern for `to` when you should have written a plain url. Also clarify: What url should `one` and `two` have so that they are reached? Is Login supposed to only show if the user is not logged in, and if they are what component is supposed to be rendered etc?

Comment: could you elaborate with my example.. that would be great..

Answer (score 0):

**1.**  Addition `{this.props.children}` in your `App.js` like this:

```js
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
        <div>
            <Header />
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

and change routes file

```js
const routes =  (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/one" component={One} />
        <Route path="/two" component={Two} />
  </Route>
)
export default routes
```

to show header all the time like navbar.

**2.**
Simple authentication example

[react-router auth example](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js)